# base64 string to input type file using jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have uploaded image using input type="file" and cropped it using JCrop. The cropped image is stored in hidden field as follows

```
<input type="hidden" name="imgCropped" id="imgCropped" />
$('#imgCropped').val(canvas.toDataURL());
```

Now I want to send this image to the controller as a HttpPostedFile. i.e I want to set the hidden field value as the value of input file type. How can I achieve this?.

```
<input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="file" />
```

Comment: Send it as content of image (as string) to backend

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but this should work.

```js
$.post( controllerUrl, { image: $("#imgCropped").val() }, function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

PS. Sorry for that synax error I edited

Comment: instead of '.result', i should add '#imgCropped'?

Comment: no .result is the place where you store the result that comes from the request. The result comes back after the controller finished its work.

Comment: It isnt working. its taking the original image which i uploaded and not the cropped image.

Comment: Ok sorry you are right. I edited the code. Now it should take the cropped image

Comment: it still isnt. I have writen the above code on submit button click event.

Comment: so what is your controllerUrl? what is the error you are getting from console? What do you get from backend? Can you test these for me in order to help you. Usually this code puts all the base64 string into 'image'. Then at the backend you can get it by calling the 'image' index of the POST array. Example in php.
$_POST['image'] gives you the base64 back. using base64_decode() would give you the image decoded. you can save that to a file. But be careful about security issues :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174925/discussion-between-ashita-shah-and-peshraw-h-ahmed).

Answer (score -1):

If you do like that na
`<input type="hidden" name="imgCropped" id="imgCropped" />`
we can't send the image into backend ,so we can hide that input textfield manually using css

```
<style>
```

`body{`
`display:none;`
`}`

then you can send the image into backend